# Contact-list API for syncing contacts from choosed Contact-list?

Tags: eventbrite

we need Contact-list API for syncing contacts from EventBrite to our application.In API documentation this contact-list API is not included ,mailChimp this type of integration is exist,ie..importing the contacts from configured EventBrite account to list in MailChimp this is an awesome integration .API for this type of integration?

Answer (score 0):

These notes might be useful: https://gist.github.com/6a66d93a54a69d4e3f50